# What is wrong with this link?

Tags: php, drupal-7, stripe-payments

Drupal 7 and windows installation Stripe Payment Module installed and dependencies as per https://www.drupal.org/project/stripe_payment

The Payment module has the following code in payments.ui.inc

```
  if (payment_method_access('create', $payment_method)) {
    $items[] = array(
      'title' => $controller->title,
      'href' => 'admin/config/services/payment/method/add/' . $controller->name,
      'description' => $controller->description,
      'localized_options' => array(),
    );
```

the controller  \Drupal\stripe_payment\CreditCardController is added so the link "Add Payment method" produces a list (un this case with one entry)

"Stripe Credit Card" .

href is set to  /admin/config/services/payment/method/add/\Drupal\stripe_payment\CreditCardController

Clicking the link fails immediately with NOT FOUND (Drupal is not processing the request).

The browser is sending  a GET to http://127.0.0.1/admin/config/services/payment/method/add/\Drupal\stripe_payment\CreditCardController

RESPONSE CODE 404.

All modules are up yo date. I install them yesterday.
This is so basic it ought ti work yet maybe I have not configured something.

TIA

Ephraim

Comment: don't mix ``\`` and `/` paths...`/` is the directory separator for URLs, not ``\``.

Comment: Look at the link in your question. Notice anything wrong with it? Look at the colours.

Comment: Yes. This is NOT my code. Its the stripe_payment module. Surely I am not the first user!! They are concatenation the namespace class to the url.

Answer (score 0):

This release fixes the issue. 7.x-1.x-dev  2015-Sep-27